# Is there a way to use a string from an array as a JSON field name?

Tags: javascript

I have an ASP.NET Page with a dropdownlist control - I want to eliminate a post back so I have wired the onclient change event to a js function. Since this drop down feeds a lot of controls with data, I am sending the JS an array of clientIds and the associated JSON field name from the returned data (which is acquired via a WebMethod call which returns JSON data for the record).

Below is just a subset of the amount of clientIds I am dealing with (probably 25 total)

**c#**

```csharp
protected override void OnRegisterScript()
{
  UxSellerShareholderDdl.OnChange =
      $"SellerShareholder_OnChange(this,{getAllClientIds()});";
}
protected struct ClientId
{
  public string fieldName;
  public string clientId;
}
protected string getAllClientIds()
{
  List<ClientId> ids = new List<ClientId>();
  ids.Add(new ClientId{fieldName = "StreetAddress", clientId = SAddresslbl.ClientID});
  ids.Add(new ClientId{fieldName = "PostalCode",    clientId = SZiplbl.ClientID});
  ids.Add(new ClientId{fieldName = "ContactName",   clientId = SMainContactlbl.ClientID});
  return new jsonScriptSerializer().Serialize(ids);
}
```

**javascript**

```js
function SellerShareholder_OnChange(ddl, ctrlList) {
  waitOn();
  PageMethods.UpdateShareholderInfo(GetSelectedOptionValue(ddl), onSuccess, onError);

  function onSuccess(result) {
    const data = JSON.parse(result);
    console.log(data);        
    for(let i = 0; i < ctrlList.length; i++) {
      let obj = ctrlList[i];
      let fld = obj.fieldName;
      if (fld === "PostalCode") {
        var id       = document.getElementById(obj.clientId);
        var idhdn    = document.getElementById(obj.clientId+"hdn");
        idhdn.value  = data.PostalCode;
        id.innerHTML = data.PostalCode;
      }
      if (fld === "StreetAddress") {
        var id       = document.getElementById(obj.clientId);
        var idhdn    = document.getElementById(obj.clientId+"hdn");
        idhdn.value  = data.StreetAddress;
        id.innerHTML = data.StreetAddress;
      }
      if (fld === "ContactName") {
        var id       = document.getElementById(obj.clientId);
        var idhdn    = document.getElementById(obj.clientId+"hdn");
        idhdn.value  = data.ContactName;
        id.innerHTML = data.ContactName;
      }
    }
    waitOff();
  }

  function onError(result) {
    waitOff();
    alert('Something wrong.');
  }
}
```

Instead of all the `fld === "Address"` then `ctrl.innerHTML = data.Address` can this be simplified in the loop to do something like `ctrl.innerHTML = data.{fld}` (so it equates to `data.Address`)?

Are there better ways in general to achieve what I am trying to accomplish here?

Comment: [Bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation). `data[fld]`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bracket notation:

`object.property` is semantically equivalent in general to `object["property"]` in JS and other dynamic languages (such as Python). The first is called *dot notation*, while the second, *bracket notation*.
Take a look on [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/dot-notation-vs-square-brackets-javascript/) article for more info on it.

Furthermore, you can do:

`idhdn.value = data[fid];`

To give an example with a value, if for instance `fid` is `StreetAddress`, this will do:

`idhdn.value = data["StreetAddress"];`

Kudos to @pilchard for mentioning bracket notation to comments.
This is the full, detailed answer.

Update: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/accessing-an-object-property-with-a-dynamically-computed-name) question.

Comment: Fair point - did not notice this duplicate mention in the comments.